# Sequelize Model Mocking findAll and findOne using sequelize-mock and jest

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, sequelize.js

For my User's CRUD, I am writing a UNIT test using [sequelize-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-mock) and [jest](http://jestjs.io/). Model mocking works for me but my issue is regarding the mock model `findAll()` and `findOne()` calling both of them in my Users test suite both returns the queued results I defined in my mock model. I'm expecting that if i call `findAll()`, I should get all the data that are defined in my queued results and if i call `findOne()` I should only get one data from the queued result based on the id i passed. Setting mock model `autoQueryFallback: false` doesn't work for me.

Here is a code snippet:

In my `controllers/users.js`

```
module.exports = {
    async list (req, res) {
        Users.findAndCountAll({
            limit: 10,
            offset: 0
        }).then(data => {
            console.log('Users >>> ', data);
        });
    },
    async view (req, res) {
        Users.findOne({
            where: { id: req.params.id }
        }).then(data => {
            console.log('User Data by ID >>> ', data);
        });
    }
};
```

To mock my users model, I have to create a `__mocks__` directory adjacent to the models (this is how Jest works). So, I have this directory structure in my models

```
> models/users.js
> models/__mocks__/users.js
```

```
const Users = dbMock.define('users', {}, { autoQueryFallback: false });
Users.$queueResult([
    Users.build({
        id: 1,
        email: 'testActive@test.com',
        fullname : 'Test Active Users',
        status: 'active', 
    }),
    Users.build({
        id: 2,
        email: 'testDeleted@test.com',
        fullname: 'Test Deleted Users',
        status: 'deleted', 
    }),
]);
```

#### Mocks

I want to test both users.list and users.view using the set of data's in my mocked model

```
jest.mock('../models/users');
describe('Testing use.list()', () => {
    it('UsersController.list() should return a status code 201 and all Users data in object array', async () => {
        await users.list(req, res);
        expect(res.json).toBeCalledWith(
            expect.objectContaining({
                data: expect.any(Object)
            })
        );
    });
    it('UsersController.view() should return a status code 201 and user data obj', async () => {
        //Passed req.params.id = 2
        await user.login(req, res);
        expect(res.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(failureCode);
        expect(res.json).toBeCalledWith(
            expect.objectContaining({
                data: expect.any(Object)
            })
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? I'm running into the same case scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$useHandler(handler) -> QueryInterface](https://sequelize-mock.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/queryinterface/#usehandlerhandler-queryinterface) can do this. We can return different query results based on `query` and `queryOptions`.

E.g.

`models/users.js`:

```js
// define user model
module.exports = {};
```

`controller/users.js`:

```js
const Users = require('../models/users');

module.exports = {
  async list(req, res) {
    return Users.findAndCountAll({
      limit: 10,
      offset: 0,
    }).then((data) => {
      console.log('Users >>> ', data);
      res.status(201).json({ data });
    });
  },
  async view(req, res) {
    return Users.findOne({
      where: { id: req.params.id },
    }).then((data) => {
      console.log('User Data by ID >>> ', data);
      res.status(201).json({ data });
    });
  },
};
```

`controller/users.test.js`:

```js
const users = require('./users');

jest.mock('../models/users', () => {
  const SequelizeMock = require('sequelize-mock');
  const dbMock = new SequelizeMock();
  const UserMock = dbMock.define('user');
  UserMock.$queryInterface.$useHandler((query, queryOptions) => {
    if (query === 'findAndCountAll') {
      return { count: 2, rows: [UserMock.build({ id: 1 }), UserMock.build({ id: 2 })] };
    } else if (query === 'findOne') {
      return UserMock.build({ id: queryOptions[0].where.id });
    }
  });
  return UserMock;
});

describe('Testing use.list()', () => {
  it('UsersController.list() should return a status code 201 and all Users data in object array', async () => {
    const req = {};
    const res = { status: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(), json: jest.fn() };
    await users.list(req, res);
    expect(res.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(201);
    expect(res.json).toBeCalledWith(
      expect.objectContaining({
        data: expect.objectContaining({
          count: 2,
          rows: expect.arrayContaining([
            expect.objectContaining({
              id: expect.any(Number),
              createdAt: expect.any(Date),
              updatedAt: expect.any(Date),
            }),
          ]),
        }),
      }),
    );
  });
  it('UsersController.view() should return a status code 201 and user data obj', async () => {
    const req = { params: { id: 2 } };
    const res = { status: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(), json: jest.fn() };
    await users.view(req, res);
    expect(res.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(201);
    expect(res.json).toBeCalledWith(
      expect.objectContaining({
        data: expect.objectContaining({
          id: 2,
          createdAt: expect.any(Date),
          updatedAt: expect.any(Date),
        }),
      }),
    );
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  src/examples/stackoverflow/62455442/controller/users.test.js
  Testing use.list()
    ✓ UsersController.list() should return a status code 201 and all Users data in object array (12ms)
    ✓ UsersController.view() should return a status code 201 and user data obj (12ms)

  console.log src/examples/stackoverflow/62455442/controller/users.js:9
    Users >>>  {
      count: 2,
      rows: [
        fakeModelInstance {
          options: [Object],
          _values: [Object],
          dataValues: [Object],
          hasPrimaryKeys: true,
          __validationErrors: []
        },
        fakeModelInstance {
          options: [Object],
          _values: [Object],
          dataValues: [Object],
          hasPrimaryKeys: true,
          __validationErrors: []
        }
      ]
    }

  console.log src/examples/stackoverflow/62455442/controller/users.js:17
    User Data by ID >>>  fakeModelInstance {
      options: {
        timestamps: true,
        paranoid: undefined,
        createdAt: undefined,
        updatedAt: undefined,
        deletedAt: undefined,
        isNewRecord: true
      },
      _values: {
        id: 2,
        createdAt: 2023-03-21T06:19:42.373Z,
        updatedAt: 2023-03-21T06:19:42.373Z
      },
      dataValues: {
        id: 2,
        createdAt: 2023-03-21T06:19:42.373Z,
        updatedAt: 2023-03-21T06:19:42.373Z
      },
      hasPrimaryKeys: true,
      __validationErrors: []
    }

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.794s, estimated 3s
```

package versions:

```json
"sequelize-mock": "^0.10.2",
"jest": "^29.5.0",
"sequelize": "^5.21.3",
```